# Configure vimrc based on environment variables

Tags: vim, spork

Is it possible to configure vimrc command mapping based on env variables?

For example, I'm using vim-ruby-test plugin which provides the following config:

```
let g:rubytest_cmd_test = "ruby %p"
```

I want to set the command differently based on whether i'm running tests using spork or not:

With Spork:

```
$ TESTDRB=y mvim .
let g:rubytest_cmd_test = "testdrb %p"
```

Without Spork:

```
$ mvim .
let g:rubytest_cmd_test = "ruby %p"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if $TESTDRB == 'y'
    let g:rubytest_cmd_test = 'ruby %p'
endif
" etc
```